# converting multidimensional hash to array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a array of json like the one I have given below

```
[
    {"Name": {"xxx": [{"I": "FORENAME"} , {"I": "Surname"}]}},
    {"EmailAddress":{"I": "yyy"}},
    {"[ID]": {"I": "zzz"}},
    {"[Company]": {"I": "aaa"}}
]
```

this has to be converted like

```
[
    ["Name", ["xxx", [["I", "FORENAME"], ["I", "Surname"]]]],
    ["EmailAddress", ["I", "yyy"]],
    ["[ID]", ["I", "zzz"]],
    ["[Company]", ["I", "aaa"]]
]
```

i am able to convert single dimension json to array using the **map** function

```
$.map( dimensions, function( value, index ) {
  ary.push([index, value])
});
```

but converting it to work with multiple dimension is difficult. Is there any methods to convert json like this or any work around..?

Comment: Recursion may be a good place to start. Are you familiar with that idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** and **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** with **[recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion)**

```js
var dimensions = [{
  "Name": {
    "xxx": [{
      "I": "FORENAME"
    }, {
      "I": "Surname"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "EmailAddress": {
    "I": "yyy"
  }
}, {
  "[ID]": {
    "I": "zzz"
  }
}, {
  "[Company]": {
    "I": "aaa"
  }
}];

function gen(data) {
  // checking data is an object
  if (typeof data == 'object') {
    // checking it's an array
    if (data instanceof Array)
      // if array iterating over it
      return data.map(function(v) {
        // recursion
        return gen(v);
      });
    else
      // if it's an object then generating array from it
      return $.map(data, function(value, index) {
        // pushing array value with recursion
        return [index, gen(value)];
      });
  }
  // returning data if not an object
  return data;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(gen(dimensions), null, 3) + '</pre>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
var oldOBJ = [
    {"Name": {"xxx": [{"I": "FORENAME"} , {"I": "Surname"}]}},
    {"EmailAddress":{"I": "yyy"}},
    {"[ID]": {"I": "zzz"}},
    {"[Company]": {"I": "aaa"}}
]

var newOBJ =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldOBJ).replace(/\{/g,"[").replace(/\}/g,"]").replace(/:/g,","));

document.write(JSON.stringify(newOBJ));
```

Comment: Looks fragile; what if you have braces inside the strings?

Comment: And what if you don't :) just being pragmatic !